# Why are my parameters in Tableau slowing down processor? I am connected via Custom SQL Query via a View

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, parameters, tableau-api

I have an `SQL Database` (SQL Server 2008 r2) that I link to **Tableau** via a **Custom SQL Query** (`connected to a view in SQL`).  Instead of adding the new fields in the SQL Database, I am creating **calculated fields** in Tableau.  `The`data source connected to Tableau is a view`I created by joining other views` (`there is a pivot I join to the main table`).  **I want to now add the parameters from tableau** `as new fields in SQL` **and remove them from Tableau** since it is bogging the tool down.  What do you recommend to be the best approach in this?  I have never `added fields to a view and curious how this can be achieved.`  **All of the parameters work in tableau** `only via the custom SQL query (the view created)`, `but would not if I created them from the main data table in SQL`..  I hope this makes sense.  Thank you so much for the help!  Have a great day -p

Comment: When you say view, you mean view in Tableau and in SQL Server, correct? If so, can you bold / highlight / elaborate on which belong to Tableau and which are on your SQL server for clarification?

Comment: Edited. Hope this helps :), and thank you!

Comment: Are you using `calculated fields` and `parameters` interchangeably here? In Tableau they are two distinct things. Do you mean them as the same?

Comment: they are meant as the same.  apologies

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question and the formatting certainly does not help. It sounds like you want to create new fields in your custom sql that would serve the same purpose as your calculated fields do currently. Is that correct?

Comment: All you then need to do is modify your custom SQL accordingly. If you want help with that, you will need to update your question with your custom SQL code and the contents of the calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

its always a good practice to create all your required fields calculation in sql table which will improve your performance. and create a extract connection with your table instead of live.